# Rendering PartialView with IEnumerable model is slow

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using `asp.net core 3`, I have a view with two tabs.When I change `tab`, I call a function form server and load a `PartialView` in my tab. but it is slow, I found that when it wants to render list, it gets slow

**Index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="background-color:white">
            <nav>
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#recipe">Recipes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#orders">Orders</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content my-tab shadow">
                <div id="recipe" class="tab-pane active">
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <br />                       
                        
                        <div id="recipePage" class="text-center">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="orders" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <br />
                    <div id="ordersPage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('CurTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
            var activeTab = sessionStorage.getItem('CurTab');
            LoadPartial(activeTab);
        });

function LoadPartial(type)
    {
        if (type == '#recipe') {
            url = '@Url.Action("Recipes", "Glasses")';
            $('#recipePage').load(url);
        }
        if (type == '#orders') {
            url = '@Url.Action("Orders", "Glasses")';
            $('#ordersPage').load(url);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**GlassController.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Orders()
        {
// this is for test
var orders = new List<Order>();
            var ord = new Order
            {
                Id = 1,
                State = (byte)1,
                Type = OrderType.Far
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            orders.Add(ord);
            
            return PartialView("OrderList", orders);
        }
```

**OrderList.cshtml**

```
    @model IEnumerable<Opto.Models.Order>
<style>
        .tableFixHead {
            overflow-y: auto;
            max-height: 300px;
            height: auto;
        }

            .tableFixHead thead th {
                position: sticky;
                top: 0;
            }

        th {
            background: white;
        }
    </style>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
            {
                <div class="tableFixHead">
                    <table class="table" style="border:1px solid;border-color:lightgrey">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Deposit)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RemainAmount)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalAmount)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CellPhone)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderDate)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeliveryDate)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NationalCode)
                                </th>
                                @*<th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeliveryDate)
                                </th>*@
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
    
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                var index = item.Id;
                                <tr id="staterow@(index)">                                
                                    <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Deposit)
                                    </td>
                                    <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RemainAmount)
                                    </td>
                                    <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)
                                    </td>
                                    
                                    <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CellPhone)
                                    </td>
                                    <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="deliveryDateCol" rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeliveryDate)
                                    </td>
                                    <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NationalCode)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            }
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Rendering partial with loop in it is so slow

Comment: Hi @Maryam,That may because you used for loop which loop the code 300 times.

Comment: I found that one of the reason is Html.DisplayFor. it makes it slower than we use item.